# Data Visualisation - bubble plots in python

Tags: python, visualization, seaborn

I would like visualise some data stored in a dictionary

```
foo = {'cat':5, 'dog':1, 'elephant':10}
```

as a bubble plot, with bubble sizes corresponding to the values. Ideally I would like interactivity; when hovering mouse over bubble you see the name 'cat', for example.

Any recommendations and tips for how to achieve this?

An idea I had is to create a pandas dataframe, `df =`

```
    Animals     Love    x   y
0   cat         5       0   0
1   dog         1       1   0
2   elephant    10      0   1
```

where the x, y parameters are used to tell something like seaborn the location of the bubbles, and the 'Love' determines the size of the bubbles.  This feels somewhat clunky, especially as I have many more than 3 rows. I would like it if the locations of the bubbles were chosen automatically.

Of course, this is just one idea, so any suggestions are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `bokeh` python library for interactive visualization.

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/categorical.html

Combine the hover functionality in `figure` and plot circles/bubbles in place of rectangles as in the above tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a simple way to do it with `matplotlib` but if you don't mind a browser display you can try [mpld3](http://mpld3.github.io/). Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpld3

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(axisbg='#EEEEEE'))
N = 10

#     Animals     Love    x   y
# 0   cat         5       0   0
# 1   dog         1       1   0
# 2   elephant    10      0   1

x = np.array([0, 1, 0])
y = np.array([0, 0, 1])
s = np.array([5, 1, 0]) * 1000  # make circle looks bigger
c = np.array(['red', 'green', 'blue'])
labels = ['cat', 'dog', 'elephant']

scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, c=c, s=s, alpha=0.3)
ax.grid(color='white', linestyle='solid')

ax.set_title("Scatter Plot (with tooltips!)", size=20)

tooltip = mpld3.plugins.PointLabelTooltip(scatter, labels=labels)
mpld3.plugins.connect(fig, tooltip)

mpld3.show()
```

Result (label shown on hover):

[image: example]